# could i have feed back message if my email were delivered or not?

Tags: email

i am sending emails to a subscribers list , i am making tests on my email account there is some ips that doesn't deliver an email neither to inbox nor junk folder ?
how can i know if my messages were delivered to my hotmail users ?
is there a way to have the message from hotmail server when my emails arrives, message should inform if it was delivered or bounce ?

this is my header section

```
   X-TMN: [8ofF+hMmyjKRh3Sb6__[ARandom/10-L/]]
X-Originating-Email: [To]
Message-ID: <COL129-W2415BACAE671__[ARandom/10-L/]@phx.gbl>
Return-Path: my email
Subject: test
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Content-transfer-encoding: 8bit
Date: [Date]
To: [To]
From:  Hii <myemail>
Sender: <myemail>
MIME-Version: 1.0
X-OriginalArrivalTime: [Date] (UTC) FILETIME=[0FD6D090:01D0EEFC]
```

Comment: Hotmail (and now Office 365) is infamous for throwing away messages without delivering them, and claiming to the sender that they were delivered. It can _not_ be considered a reliable email service.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is MTA functionality called "Delivery Status Notification" or DSN, when destination MTA sends a small message to the submitter, like "Message was succesfully delivered to the user's Inbox".

Unfortunately, that feature is often used by spammers to determine whether the %USERNAME% exists for domain or not. Therefore this feature generally is disabled in MTAs, and `exim` even hasn't it implemented till 4.8x.

Also that feature can produce the huge backflow of notifications. So you can't estimate it is enabled on the remote MTA, and have to look some other way to achieve desired effect.

Answer (score 2):

A rule of thumb in the email echosystem. If you havent received any postfix error or delivery error its a good sign. (for a backtime of around 3 days, as if the domain and mx exist, but the remote server does not answer, it will be in the queue box for retry)

Just be advised some hoster does not sent out non delivery email, as it can be used by spammer.

Comment: Many MTAs will silently accept and drop mails with a high spam score.

Comment: @Sven thanks for clarifing, its what I meant but badly wrote.